# Do we want to be littered with these sorts of questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, languages

First of all, we have this question from four years ago:

[Check if a subview is in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421298/2792531)

Despite carrying an Objective-C tag, ultimately this question is purely just asking about an object/method out of `UIKit`, which is one of the frameworks for writing iOS application.  And even though the "pseudocode" looks quite like Objective-C, it's still not Objective-C:

> ```
> if([self popoverView] is not on rootView)
> ```

As far as I'm concerned, there's not really much wrong with this question.  It's a perfectly valid question about the `UIKit` framework.  But let's keep in mind, it's not a language specific question, not really.

Then we have this question:

[Check if a subview is in a view using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30937342/2792531)

This question asks the same question... but instead specifies "But all the answers are in Objective-C, and I want to know how to do it in Swift?"  It even links back to the question I referenced earlier in this post.  And that original answer has a link back to the official `UIView` documentation, which between the posting and now, that link has been updated to include the Swift implementation of the answer.

In fact, outside of the Objective-C-looking "pseudocode" and the language tag (since 4 years ago ObjC would've been the only language that applied), that original question doesn't even specify that answers should be in Objective-C.

So, with all that said...

In my opinion, it seems the best course of action would be to do the following:

1. Edit the original question's "pseudocode" to look less like Objective-C and more like legitimate pseudocode.  Also fix up its tags to better reflect what the  question is actually about (remove [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), add [uikit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit) and perhaps [uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uiview)).
2. Edit the accepted answer on the original question to additionally include the Swift syntax, since ultimately the answer is just (correctly) pointing to the `UIView` documentation, which documents both Swift and Objective-C (and would document any new language Apple adds in the future).
3. Close the new question as a duplicate of the original question.

I want to elaborate on point 3.  I don't think that all Swift questions can or should be closed as duplicates of Objective-C questions.  But when the question isn't about a specific problem with the Swift syntax and is purely asking the same library/framework question as an existing Objective-C question, then it's the same question.  In this specific case, I personally feel relatively strongly that the question could be closed as a duplicate *without* any edits to the older question.

Am I right in this?  Or should we let the Swift question stand in this specific case?

**Addendum:** Now that I look more closely, someone actually did add [a Swift answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864448/2792531) to that original question.